# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre usar * y & en una función como parámetro?

Tags: c++, punteros

Buenas tardes a todos recientemente he estado jugando con el tema de los punteros y me ha llegado una gran duda resulta que por ejemplo yo defino 2 funciones las cuales simplemente calcula la suma de 2 valores

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int calcular_suma(int *num_x,int *num_y){
       //como bien sabemos los que se pasa a los parametros es un tipo de dato puntero que a //su vez apuntan a algo del mismo tipo de dato
    int total = (*num_x)+(*num_y);  // como bien sabemos aqui estamos dereferenciando al //puntero para saber cual es el valor al que apunta 
 return total;
// todo excelente hasta aqui 
}
int main (){
   int num_x=60,num_y=10;
   printf("La suma total fue --->%i",calcular_suma(num_x,num_y));
//escelente no todo bien hasta aqui 
}
// el problema  biene cuando en vez de declarar  asi la funcion la declaramos de la siguiente forma
int calcular_suma(int &num_x,int &num_y){  //Mi duda es esta cual seria la diferenciae entre la declaracion  anterior  y esta ? 
}
//ademas en el main como le pasaria los parametros a esta funcion?
//cual es mejor y porque?
//y si fuera poco vean miren esta otra declaracion 
int calcular_suma(int *&num_x,int *&num_y){ //e de aclarar  que el compilador no da error pero que sucede aqui como se pasaria ?? WTF!
//como prodecederiamos con esta y como le pasamos sus parametros  en la funcion principal main?

}
```

Comment: `*` indica que estás pasando un puntero al parámetro y `&` que estás pasando el parámetro por referencia.

Comment: Cuando pasas un parámetro como puntero, lo que estás pasando es un contenedor de la referencia a tu parámetro. Si pasas un parámetro como referencia, estás pasando un alias de tu parámetro que te permite modificarlo aún fuera de tu función.

Comment: @HéctorM.pero como ? si pudieras ilustrarme seria de gran ayuda como que un alias osea que con &num_x como parametro de la funcion seria eso una referencia y podria aun asi modicarlo fuera de esa funcion? o como?

Comment: Estoy construyendo una respuesta, en un momento la publico

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Entonces quieres saber en qué se diferencia un parámetro de puntero `*` de un parámetro de referencia `&`. Esto se puede descomponer entre entender el puntero y entender la referencia.

Basaré mi respuesta en [Differences between pointers and references in C++](https://www.educative.io/answers/differences-between-pointers-and-references-in-cpp) y [Pointers vs References in C++](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointers-vs-references-cpp/).

---

**-- El puntero:**

- En C++, un puntero es una variable que almacena la dirección de memoria de otra variable.
- No es necesario inicializar el puntero durante la declaración.
- Le puedes asignar el valor `NULL`.
- Se puede desreferenciar con `*` para acceder a su contenido.
- Puedes efectuar operaciones aritméticas con él.
- Una vez declarado, puede reasignarse a una variable del mismo tipo.

**-- La referencia:**

- En C++, una referencia es un alias para una variable ya existente. Una vez que se inicializa referenciando a una variable, no puede cambiarse para que referencie otra variable.
- Es necesario inicializar la referencia durante la declaración.
- No le puedes asignar el valor `NULL`.
- No necesita ser desreferenciado, se puede usar simplemente por su nombre.
- No puedes efectuar operaciones aritméticas con ella.
- Una vez declarado, no puede reasignarse a ninguna otra variable.

---

Entendido lo anterior, veamos algunos ejemplos:

**-- Con el puntero:**

<sub>Puedes inicializar tus variables de esta forma:</sub>

```
int *x = new int(1);
int *y = new int(2);
```

<sub>De esta otra forma:</sub>

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

int *xp = &x;
int *yp = &y;
```

<sub>O con valor `NULL`:</sub>

```
int *xp = NULL;
int *yp = NULL;

int *xp = nullptr;
int *yp = nullptr;
```

**-- Con la referencia:**

<sub>Puedes inicializar tus variables de esta forma:</sub>

```
int x = 1;
int y = 2;

int &xr = x;
int &yr = y;
```

Y es que una referencia siempre apuntará a una variable declarada previamente.

Además, puedes asignar una referencia a un puntero:

```
int variable = 1;
int *puntero = &variable; // referencia
```

Porque una referencia es un alias de una variable, y este alias es el puntero que trae la referencia de la variable.

---

Si tenemos este bloque:

```
int original    = 25;
int &referencia = original;

cout << original << endl; // 25

referencia = 3;

cout << original << endl; // 3
```

Vemos que `original` adopta el valor que asignemos a `referencia`.

En cambio, con este otro:

```
int original    = 25;
int *puntero    = &original;

cout << original << endl; // 25

puntero = new int(3);

cout << original << endl; // 25
```

Por más que reasignemos `puntero`, `original` se mantiene igual.

Esto es lo que diferencia un puntero de una referencia, aunque sean equivalentes, el puntero almacena la dirección de la variable, que es lo que se obtiene al hacer `&variable` o `new Tipo` en C++, mientras que la referencia es un alias, es como si renombrásemos la misma variable.

Es decir, por ejemplo, al hacer:

```
int original    = 1;
int &referencia = original;
```

Es como si hubieses renombrado `original` por `referencia`. `referencia` se convierte en alias de `original` ya que cada operación que realices con `referencia` afectará del mismo modo a `original`. Esto no aplica a la inversa, es decir, si modificas `original` solo cambia esta variable, más no afecta a `referencia`.

Inclusive esta operción donde incremento `referencia` con el operador `++`:

```
int original    = 25;
int &referencia = original;

cout << original << endl; // 25

referencia++;

cout << original << endl; // 26
```

afecta igual al valor de `original`.

---

**¿Cuándo usar uno u otro?**

Creo que es mejor explicar con ejemplos, y los ejemplos que propondré si bien no serán exactamente como el código de tu pregunta, se acercan a usos más cotidianos de un puntero y una referencia.

<sup>Ejemplo de uso de punteros:</sup>

```
int sumar(int *x, int *y)
{
    return *x + *y;
}

int main()
{
    // Recuerda que `new` devuelve punteros
    int *x = new int(1);
    int *y = new int(2);
    
    cout << sumar(x, y);

    // No olvides que debes limpiar los punteros
    // con `delete` una vez termines de usarlos
    delete x;
    delete y;

    return 0;
}
```

<sup>Ejemplo de uso de referencias:</sup>

```
void sumar(int x, int y, int &resultado)
{
    resultado = x + y;
}

int main()
{
    int x = 1;
    int y = 2;

    // Recuerda, debes inicializar una variable si piensas usarla como referencia
    int resultado = 0;
    
    cout << resultado << endl; // 0

    // La función puede cambiar el valor de `resultado`
    // entonces ya no es necesario devolver el resultado
    sumar(x, y, resultado);
    
    cout << resultado << endl; // 3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sos la ostia en papas tio eres una clase de dios o algo asi men lo entendi perfectamente  ya de di a la palomita je para que te motives hermano gracias enserio me has salvado enserio

Comment: Héctor, un par de apuntes respecto a tus ejemplos: `nullptr` y `NULL` no son equivalentes, el primero es un literal de puntero nulo el segundo es (en muchos casos) un entero con valor cero; `NULL` no debería usarse en código moderno. En el ejemplo en que escribes `int *puntero = &variable; // referencia` la `variable` no es una referencia, es una instancia de ìnt`.

Answer (score 2):

En algunos casos se puede usar una referencia como una forma más conveniente de hacer lo mismo que harías con un puntero.

Mira este ejemplo. ¿No crees que la versión con referencias es más limpia que la de punteros?

```
int sumarRef(int& a, int& b){
    return a + b;
}

int sumarPtr(int* a, int* b){
    return *a + *b;
}

int main(){
    int a = 1, b = 2;
    sumarRef(a, b);
    sumarPtr(&a, &b);
}
```

Lo que determinará si puedes reemplazar punteros por referencias es que **los punteros pueden reasignarse y las referencias no**.

Cada uno cumple un rol en el lenguaje.

---

### Los punteros:

- Contienen direcciones de memoria. Te dan poder *casi* absoluto sobre la memoria, de no ser por [medidas de seguridad](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection) que toma el sistema operativo.
- Pueden apuntar a otros punteros.

Algunos ejemplos de uso:

- Acceder a posiciones de memoria contiguas. Sirve para recorrer un arreglo.
- Cuando reservas memoria obtienes un puntero y debes conservar una copia para liberarla.
- Aritmética. Para obtener la longitud de una cadena:

  ```
  int length(const char* str){
      const char* beginning = str;
      while (*str)
          str++;

      return str - beginning;
  }
  ```
- Leer direcciones de memoria arbitrarias. No es recomendable usar direcciones desconocidas ya que pueden ser inválidas:

  ```
  char* ptr = (char*)20;
  ```
- Puedes hacer cosas más interesantes, como ver si tu procesador es little-endian o big-endian. Convertir a otro tipo de puntero sería [comportamiento indefinido](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

  ```
  bool isLittleEndian(){
      int n = 0x11223344;
      char* firstBytePtr = (char*)&n;
      return *firstBytePtr == 0x44;
  }
  ```

---

### Las referencias

Según la [documentación](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference), son alias a objetos o funciones ya existentes, no necesariamente ocupan espacio en memoria y existen 2 tipos: `lvalue` y `rvalue`. Se denotan por los símbolos `&` e `&&` detrás del nombre respectivamente.

[Más información](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) sobre `lvalue` y `rvalue`.

Las referencias ganan protagonismo en las clases, en la [sobrecarga de operadores](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators).

Un ejemplo con constructores para [copiar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) y [mover](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor) y operadores de asignación para [copiar](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_assignment) y [mover](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_assignment):

```
class Clase {
public:
    Clase(const Clase&);
    Clase(Clase&&);

    Clase& operator=(const Clase&);
    Clase& operator=(Clase&&);
}
```

A diferencia de los punteros, no se pueden crear referencias a referencias ni punteros a referencias. Pero sí referencias a punteros.

Se aprovechan mejor como parámetros de funciones cuando quieres modificar la variable original y no la referencia.

---

### Dato curioso

Si revisas el [desensamblado](https://godbolt.org/z/1e6arPjo5) del código producido por el compilador notarás que son exactamente iguales. Internamente las referencias contienen la dirección de memoria de la variable original.

Ten en cuenta que **la implementación podría variar de un compilador a otro**.